# Travelling with small fold up wheelchair

Tags: air-travel, luggage, accessibility

Will I be charged for checking my small fold up wheelchair prior to flying Denver to LHR May 20th?

Comment: Which airline? What size? Do you have a medical requirement to use it? Are you transiting anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're traveling United or British Airways, but neither will charge to transport a wheelchair.

For British Airways, [their wheelchair information](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/disability-assistance/assistance-available#) is listed online (scroll to "Assistance for mobility and wheelchairs"), including maximum dimensions. They have [a special department you can call](https://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us#) for further information if you have any questions, want to request assistance at the airport, or need to arrange accessible seating on board. You can also [request these services online](https://wheelchairtravel.org/british-airways-wheelchair-assistance/). It's your choice whether you'd like to check your chair at the check-in counter or keep it until the gate, and if space permits, they may have room for it in the cabin instead of the cargo hold.

[United's policy](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/special-needs/disabilities/customer-wheelchair.html) is similar: "United Airlines will accept a customer's wheelchair or other assistive device in addition to the checked baggage allowance at no additional charge." They have [further information online](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/specialneeds/disabilities/default.aspx), and you can contact them or request online if you would like assistance at the airport or an aisle-chair on the plane.